# What triggers the popup blockers in browsers?

Tags: javascript, popup

In what circumstances do blockup blockers in browsers activate, and in what circumstances do they not?

Can you ever use an onclick event on a link to trigger a popup (other than target = _blank) or will that always trigger the blockers?

Answer (score 4):

Most popup blockers are triggered when a popup is launched indirectly from a user action.

Some popup blockers are triggered when a user clicks, but most are not.  Basically, if the popup is triggered within a click handler (or code that it calls), you are generally okay.

If possible, I would recommend avoiding popups entirely.  They tend to disrupt the user experience, with a few exceptions.

Comment: I agree. A more user friendly solution/alternative of popups in a web application is to create a centered opaque div on the page, with some transparent mask behind it to mask other controls (like lightbox js).

Comment: Completely agree with workflow issues  / design.  Its calling the FB auth login though, not something i can redesign into a sidebar. Clicking on a link calls a function which eventually shows the FB login dialog  - which gets blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty detailed [answer](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/400557.html) about pop-ups. Yes you can use an onclick event to trigger a popup and generally that's how ad companies make money -- they track your click to know you have seen the pop-up ad and count it so the people sending the pop-up to you get money.

Also here is a pretty detailed [article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/pop-up-blocker.htm) on how pop-up blockers work.